# Error reading int from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am try to retrieve an `int` from Firebase but I am getting this some error.

This is the codo to retrive the data:

```
Birthday = dataSnapshot.child(userID).child("data_birth").getValue(int.class);
```

The ERROR is this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
```

But this String I can retrive:

```
Email = dataSnapshot.child(userID).child("email").getValue(String.class);
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to determine the cause of the problem, beyond what the error message already says: there is no child `data_birth` in the snapshot. If you want better help, update your question to show the JSON data at the location you're reading, and the minimal **but complete** code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `dataSnapshot.child(userID).child("data_birth")` return `Null`, you can null checking.

```
if (dataSnapshot.child(userID).child("data_birth")==null)
    Birthday = 0;
else 
    Birthday = dataSnapshot.child(userID).child("data_birth").getValue(Integer.class);
```